# PWA display standalone & fullscreen not working after add ServiceWorkerModule in Angular 5

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, displaymode

### Current behavior

After add configuration to app module `environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js') : []` and enable `serviceWorker` in .angular-cli.json, my application after install on my device (LG G6) through Chrome with property `display` in manifest.json set on `standalone` or `fullscreen` after open on my device, the application always open in browser in new tab.
When I remove service worker config (row in app module), app with only manifest open in standalone or fullscreen mode.

### Expected behavior

After install app, application should open in stadalone or fullscreen mode, depends on set value in manifest.json.

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

I have application generated with version 4.3 and updated to 5.1.3, add @angular/service-worker and generate with angular cli `build` with `--prod`. For serving the application, I use port forwarding in my chrome.

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "FindPark",
  "name": "Find Nearby Car Parks",
  "start_url": "/search",

  "theme_color": "#206886",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",

  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",

  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/favicon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/favicon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/favicon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/favicon-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/favicon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

I don't know why isn't working with my application because I find example similar to my app https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/hnpwa-angular-5-progressive-web-app-service-worker-tutorial/ and I clone and build and work fine (display as standalone app).

### Environment

```
Angular version: 5.1.3 (also checked with 5.0.0, 5.0.3, 5.1.0)


Browser:
- [x] Chrome (desktop) version 63.0.3239.108
- [x] Chrome (Android) version 63.0.3239.111
- [ ] Chrome (iOS) version XX
- [ ] Firefox version XX
- [ ] Safari (desktop) version XX
- [ ] Safari (iOS) version XX
- [ ] IE version XX
- [ ] Edge version XX

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: 6.11.4  
- Platform:  Linux 

Others:
@ngrx 4
rxjs 5.5.6
Android
```

Comment: Something tells me this template is from the Angular repo... 

Answer (score 5):

You say you are using port forwarding - I am not quite sure what that means here. In my experience, progressive web apps with service workers do not work correctly unless served from a standard HTTPS address. When I launch my app from a correctly configured HTTPS with a non-standard port (for example, 4567 rather than 443) the address bar will show in the app on Android.

Without the service worker (ie just using appcache) the same app from the same URL works as expected on Android with no address bar at the top.

If you keep the service worker and change the hosting so that HTTPS is on the standard 443 port, again the app works as expected on Android and opens with no address bar at the top. This seems like a bug?

Comment: THIS! you saved my life.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Custom ports indeed do not work as expected. The PWA launches in regular browser mode and gets none of the benefits of display-mode:standalone

Comment: I'm reasonably sure 'port forwarding' refers to the method of developing using an Android phone connected by USB to a computer that has chrome set up to forward a web server running on it to a localhost port on the phone - usually set up from the chrome://inspect page.
However, is it not true that service workers should work fine with http when served from localhost?
"However http://localhost is also considered a secure origin"
https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `manifest.json` file is missing in the dist folder when you build your app.

Probably you're missing the manifest.json in the assets array in `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "chronery-web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "manifest.json"  // Add this if it's missing!
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
```

And make sure you added it to your `index.html`:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#009688">
</head
```

Comment: I added this before.